# CSS set background style on repeating pattern

Tags: html, css

I have 6 individual divs as so although it is possible to have more than 6 children divs. What I am trying to achieve is alternating background colors. So first 3 div will have a white background, next 3 - a black background, the next 3 - white again, next three - black again, etc.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">child 1</div>
  <div class="child">child 2</div>
  <div class="child">child 3</div>
  <div class="child">child 4</div>
  <div class="child">child 5</div>
  <div class="child">child 6</div>
</div>
```

I have tried a few ways with nth-child selector but haven't been able to achieve this pattern. Thanks much.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? I really don't get what your trying to ask.

Comment: `:nth-child(6n+1), :nth-child(6n+2), :nth-child(6n+3) {background-color:white} :nth-child(6n+4), :nth-child(6n+5), :nth-child(6n+6) {background-color:black}`

Comment: if the list of children is constant then Niet the Dark Absol's solution would work - javascript would solve this problem easily